# Why `ardalis/CleanArchitecture` reference FastEndpoints but not it's own `ardalis/ApiEndpoints`

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, minimal-apis, ardalis-cleanarchitecture

Just need a clarification.

I was keen on referencing [`ApiEndpoints`](https://github.com/ardalis/ApiEndpoints) in one of my projects.
But when I am browsing the `ardalis/CleanArchitecture` repo I noted it has been using `FastEndpoints` [ref](https://github.com/ardalis/CleanArchitecture/blob/main/src/Clean.Architecture.Web/Program.cs).

The question is why they have deviated from their own implementation and use another lib for the same purpose.

Appreciate your feedback.

Comment: thought you might find this [twitter reply](https://twitter.com/ardalis/status/1665520774722060289) from ardalis interesting regarding the matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe because the performance of FastEndpoints is much better than the Ardalis implementation. However, in both of them you can implement the CleanArchitecture.

In my opinion, using FastEndpoints give you more flexibility, easier, yet better performance.

---

***Update:***

Steve mentioned it in [this tweet](https://twitter.com/ardalis/status/1665520774722060289)

Answer (score 1):

The template gives examples of using multiple libraries/frameworks including FastEndpoints ([example](https://github.com/ardalis/CleanArchitecture/blob/main/src/Clean.Architecture.Web/Endpoints/ContributorEndpoints/Create.cs)), Ardalis.ApiEndpoints ([example](https://github.com/ardalis/CleanArchitecture/blob/main/src/Clean.Architecture.Web/Endpoints/ProjectEndpoints/Create.cs)), and MVC ([example](https://github.com/ardalis/CleanArchitecture/blob/main/src/Clean.Architecture.Web/Controllers/ProjectController.cs)).